# Two columns on same row with bootstrap 3.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to place two columns on the same row with Bootstrap 3.2, but am not having any success.

The format that I want is something like this:
BeginDate: txbox1    EndDate: txtbox2

My code is as follows, but I know it's incorrect.

**I would appreciate it very much for someone more experienced in Bootstrap for a solution.**

```
<label for="dteBeginDate" class="col-md-2 control-label">Begin Date:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="date" id="dteBeginDate">
                </div>
                <label for="dteEndDate" class="col-md-2 control-label">End Date:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="date" id="dteEndDate">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bootstrap 3 has a 12 unit width column grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), so this means that each row can have up to 12 columns, and additional columns will be stacked below as another rows. You are setting 24 units (*col-md-2* + *col-md-10* + *col-md-2* + *col-md-10*), so the second pair of columns are moving to another row (remember that the number post-fix in the class names indicates the column length). Reduce the units to 12, placing them within a "row" class div for completeness (it doesn't constraint that all the elements will be within a single row, though). For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <label for="dteBeginDate" class="col-md-2 control-label">Begin Date:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="date" id="dteBeginDate">
  </div>
  <label for="dteEndDate" class="col-md-2 control-label">End Date:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="date" id="dteEndDate">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Demo: http://jsbin.com/yukut/1/edit

I think what you are looking for is the `form-inline`. Look at the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

```
   <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="begin_date">Begin Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="begin_date" placeholder="Start Date">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="end_date">End Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="end_date" placeholder="End Date">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I will make two changes to help you out. The first being to place the label inside the div otherwise you are actually making 4 columns (label, input, label, input). The second being that bootstraps [gridsystem](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is broken into 12 columns per 1 row and your original code used 24 columns (2 label, 10 input, 2 label, 10 input). Check out the bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/CN1OBG6kxq)

**Code**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Begin Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dteBeginDate">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>End Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="dteEndDate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```